# Sprite kit impulse at point

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

[image: example image]

I'm trying to use two points on a spaceship to create a "tank like movement" were the space ship will move forward when both points get an impulse on the `physicsBody` (using the `applyImpulse(CGVector, atPoint: CGPoint)` method) and turn left/right when only one point gets an impulse.

I can move the space ship forward using the `applyImpulse(CGVector)` method without the `atPoint` parameter and it works, but i have issues using the `atPoint` parameter.

When trying to use the atPoint parameter the spaceship will move really randomly, even if i apply an impulse to both jet engine 1 and jet engine 2, but i'm not sure if i apply the forces at the right point (on the jet engine spots marked on the image), the documentation is very vague about this and i don't know how to get the position of the impulses right.

Does anyone know how to get the correct positions to apply the impulses to? It should be like the ones on the image. I'm using Swift but i can read Objective C so that doesn't really matter.

EDIT:
I have tried the following points:

```
CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) and CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)    
CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) and CGPoint(x: spaceship.size.width, y: 0)
```

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh I just edited the post with the two sets of points i tried to use

Comment: @CorPruijs as I said, you should probably be using the y axis. Or at least, with the image you have shown, those points are offset on the y-axis and not the x.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh I already fixed it, i should have noted that the spaceship was currently turned by π/2 (in radians).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reviewing the documentation, the points you apply the impulses at must be in scene coordinates. What that means, is you need to determine the points in the coordinates of your sprite (probably coordinates like `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)` and `CGPoint(x: 0, y: -1)`, but you may need to play with those), then convert those to scene coordinates using `convertPoint(point, fromNode: ship)`.

Comment: The [SpriteKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html) has a wealth of information on the coordinate systems in use for the various nodes. Of interest to you though is probably that of the `SKSpriteNode` found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW36). You will just want to play around with the `y` values most likely.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this that's (possibly) going to give you a more "realistic" drag and thrust result is hanging two engine bodies off your fighter jet, and giving them both drag properties, and apply thrust from them when needed, as needed.

In this way you'll get the type of rotation common to one engine being on whilst the other is off, etc.